# When using Hibernate as JPA provider, can I use HQL features?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql, jpql

I am using JPA 2.0. Hibernate 4.1 is the provider. Can I use HQL features?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

At least that can be deduced from the following:

> 11.4.8.3. Non-standardized functions
>
> Hibernate Dialects can register additional functions known to be available for that particular database product. These functions are also **available in HQL (and JPQL, though only when using Hibernate as the JPA provider obviously).**

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html

Comment: And thought the whole point of JPA is to provide a standard, like 90% of serious projects use hibernate, if not more.

Comment: I do "serious" projects and I don't use Hibernate, and know of many people who also use other jpa implementations. Perhaps you mean that it is strange to use vendor specific features when that throws away portability.